# Cannot set bucket policy of amazon s3

Tags: amazon-s3

I was simply following the "get started"  tutorial [here](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/build-serverless-web-app-lambda-apigateway-s3-dynamodb-cognito/module-1/)

But I failed at "Step 4 Add a Bucket Policy to Allow Public Reads". It always complains "access denied" with a red error icon.

I am not able to set it via command line either. Here is the command I use:

> aws s3api put-bucket-policy --bucket bucket-name --policy
>   file://bucket-policy.json

Here is the error I got:

> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutBucketPolicy
>   operation: Access Denied

Comment: the policy u attached just provides a read access! are you doing anything other then reading from your bucket ?

Comment: No. I am just going thru tutorial. I am not able to set policy.

Comment: can paste the policy that you are setting here. also, can you make sure if u have replaced `[YOUR_BUCKET_NAME]` in `arn:aws:s3:::[YOUR_BUCKET_NAME] ` with the correct bucket name ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue was, you have to uncheck the boxes under permissions -> public access settings. Amazon failed to mention this in their tutorial. Bad tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

When creating a new bucket, default policy doesn't grant public access (Amazon S3 Block Public Access is enabled). If your new bucket policy grants public access, you need to run this at first for existing bucket:

```
aws s3api delete-public-access-block --bucket ${BUCKET_NAME}
```